# Get images from json with $http, get only first one

Tags: angularjs, json, api

This is the js file, how can i access to the images section and show only first in html ?

```js
var Test = angular.module('test', []);

Test.controller('hotelsController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

  var images;

  $scope.getHotels = function() {
    $http.get('http://fake-hotel-api.herokuapp.com/api/hotels')
      .success(function(data) {
        $scope.hotels = data;
        images = data[0].images;
        console.log(angular.fromJson(images));
      })
      .error(function(data) {
        $scope.hotels = "Response failed";
      });
  }
}]);

<p>This is the css of the tests</p>
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 50px
}

.container {
  width: 1630px;
  margin: 0 auto
} 

body {
  font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
  color: #000
}

.btn-grey {
  background: #e5e5e5;
  width: 320px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 47px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #323232;
  font-size: 26px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #979797
}

.btn-grey:hover {
  color: #323232;
  background: #ccc
}

.hotels .hotel {
  height: 480px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 115px;
  border: 1px solid #979797;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 48px
}

.hotels .hotel .hotel-image {
  width: 654px;
  border-right: 1px solid #979797;
  float: left;
  background: #e5e5e5;
  height: 478px
}

.hotels .hotel .hotel-image img {
  height: 478px
}

.hotels .hotel .hotel-description {
  width: calc(100% - 655px);
  float: left;
  padding: 0 35px;
  background: #f6f6f6;
  position: relative;
  height: 478px
}

.hotels .hotel .hotel-description .hotel-stars {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px
}

.hotels .hotel .hotel-description h2 {
  font-size: 42px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #000;
  margin: 35px 0 20px
}

.hotels .hotel .hotel-description h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0 0 50px
}

.hotels .hotel .hotel-description p {
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 26px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  height: 78px;
  overflow: hidden
}

.hotels .hotel .hotel-description .hotel-price {
  float: right;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: #323232;
  text-align: right
}

.hotels .hotel .hotel-description .hotel-price .date {
  display: block;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 300
}

<p>This is the html of the file</p>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="test">
  <h1>Test</h1>

  <div class="container" ng-controller="hotelsController">
    <center><a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="getHotels()" class="btn-grey">Load Hotels</a></center>
    <div class="hotels" ng-cloak>
      <div class="hotel clearfix" ng-repeat="item in hotels | limitTo:5">
        <div class="hotel-image">
          <img ng-src="{{item.images | limitTo:1}}" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="hotel-description">
          <div class="hotel-stars">
            {{item.stars}} &#9733;
          </div>
          <h2>{{item.name}}</h2>
          <h3>{{item.city}} - {{item.country}}</h3>
          <p>
            {{item.description}}
          </p>
          <a href="#" class="btn-grey">Show Reviews</a>
          <div class="hotel-price">
            {{item.price}} &euro;
            <span class="date">
                              {{item.date_start | date}} - {{item.date_end | date}}
                          </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

if i put only {{item.images}} i will return me ["..linktoimage"] and i need to remove brackets and quotation marks

See code sniped here

Comment: Please format your question. its impossible to understand anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem being you're assigning an array (with just one item) to the img's src rather than passing the actual img url string, so tweak this bit, it should be fixed:

```
<div class="hotel clearfix" ng-repeat="item in hotels | limitTo:5">
        <div class="hotel-image">
          <img ng-src="{{(item.images.length>0?item.images[0]:'')}}" alt="">
        </div>
...
```

Comment: Thx man it works! Can you just explain me what did you just do? :D

Comment: You're welcome! When you use {{item.images | limitTo:1}} the result would be of Array type with just 1 element. So when it's being used as a string (in this case image src) then it stringifies the Array not your desired element. What I did was just checking if item.images have at least 1 element and if that's the case returning item.images[0] which is the first element in item.images array.otherwise it returns an empty string. Adding this condition is just to avoid errors when item.images is empty.

Comment: Can i ask you one more thing ? I have struggle with stars in this same project. In Json i have number of stars 2,3.... And how to transform it in unicode &#9733 and not to be a number just to get 2 or 3 unuicode characters?

Comment: So, lets assume you have an object called obj and a variable called ranking (which is your string containing the stars or asterisks) , then rather than using {{obj.ranking}} you can use
 `{{obj.ranking.replace(/\*/g,'\u2605') }}`   the \u2605 is the Hex equivalent of the decimal 9733

Comment: sorry I couldn't type it correctly in the comments so I pasted the correct one in a new answer.

Comment: i'm quite new in Angular. Just started to learn.
I put  {{item.stars.replace(/\*/g,'\u2605')}} for this case and it gives me error.


[$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 20-20 [\] in expression [item.stars.replace(/\*/g,'\u2605')].

Comment: Please copy/paste from the answer I posted. There should be a backslash before the asterisk : `replace(/\*/g,'\u2605')`

Comment: I copied first time.
I put this but it is the same error.

`{{item.stars.replace(/\*/g,'\u2605')}}`

Comment: sorry you're right. I edited my last answer, check it out to see the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Define this method in your controller :

```
 $scope.getReplacedStars = function(input)
        {
            return input.replace(/\*/g, '\u2605');
        }
```

then use it in the HTML:

```
{{getReplacedStars(item.stars)}}
```